# Spotify Application- Not able to post facebook using jquery & access token

Tags: javascript, spotify

Friends,
I am developing third party application on Spotify.
I am using Spotify Client to access my developer menu.
Currentyl i am getting access token using spotify library but i am not able to post facebook wall using accesstoken & $.post() method?
Anybody have idea cause for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change your manifest.json in the RequiredPermissions section ? 
Don't forget to restart Spotify after changing it.

GPsnail